# Como puedo evitar que salgan valores vacios al usar each

Tags: javascript, sql-server, nodejs, handlebars.js, mssql

Hola a todos buenas tardes:

Estoy creando un proyecto con nodejs, mssql , y handlebars y al momento de hacer una consulta a la base de datos y mandarla a una vista con **res.render** y recibirla con **each** no lo imprime solamente hasta que pongo:

```
{{#each drivers}}
   {{#each this}}
      <h3>{{Nombres}}</h3>
    {else}}
    {{/each}}
  {{/each}}
```

de esa manera si me la imprime pero con valores vacios al principio y al final del array (muestro codigo de como me lo arroja:

```
 <h3></h3>
 <h3>Fernando</h3>
 <h3>Irvin</h3>
 <h3>Carolina</h3>
 <h3></h3>
```

Este es el código con el que lo envió a la vista:

```
router.get('/',async (req,res)=>{
    const drivers=await db.query("select * from dbo.PruebaApp");
    console.dir(drivers);
    res.render('links/showDrivers', {drivers} );
});
```

y esto es lo que me arroja la consola npm:

```
{
  recordsets: [ [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ] ],
  recordset: [
    {
      Personid: 1,
      Nombres: 'Fernando',
      Apellidos: 'Lopez',
      Correo: 'ferchitoxs@gmail.com'
    },
    {
      Personid: 2,
      Nombres: 'Irvin',
      Apellidos: 'Lopez',
      Correo: 'ferchitoxs@gmail.com'
    },
    {
      Personid: 3,
      Nombres: 'Carolina',
      Apellidos: 'Mena',
      Correo: 'licmena@gmail.com'
    }
  ],
  output: {},
  rowsAffected: [ 3 ]
}
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta esto

```
{{#each drivers}}
   {{#each this}}
      {{#if Nombres}}
         <h3>{{Nombres}}</h3>
      {{/if}}
   {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

Edit: Tu codigo hace iteraciones innecesarias, tu código quedaría mejor así:

```
{{#each drivers.recordset}}
   {{#if this.Nombres}}
      <h3>{{this.Nombres}}</h3>
   {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Bro!!

Comment: PD: @Fernando Lpz Mira el cambio que hice, pues tu código no es muy limpio

Comment: SI lo pongo como me comentas no sale nada incluso me marca un error.

Comment: @FernandoLpz Perdona, me equivoqué. Deja lo corrijo

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo en cuenta tu pregunta si sabes que algunos campos pueden estar vacios tienes que poner un valor por defecto. A la hora de leer los datos.

Comment: Hola , tienes algun ejemplo que pueda ver o en que basarme , soy nuevo en esto.